# I can no longer log into my Mac after “sudo chmod 744 /”

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, mac, chmod

Right after I executed:

```
sudo chmod 744 /
```

on my Mac, everything on my desktop is gone, and I can no longer open any applications or folders. So I pressed the power button to restart my Mac, but then the windows just freeze in the user log in page. Please help because I have lots of important files in this Mac.

I'm pretty sure it's simply because of the `sudo chmod 744 /` permission change via chmod and not anything else.

I assume this because I also have a Ubuntu machine, and exactly the same thing just happened when I ran that same chmod!

Now I have two unusable/unbootable systems now due to the same issue. How can I fix them?

Comment: @dsstorefile1 thanks for you reply.. The thing is I do not have any backup, and I can no longer log in to my MAC, so I can't get to the terminal....

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Thanks. Do you mean holding Command+R and go to Disk Utility to reinstall it?? Thanks again! I saw this option but just wasn't sure if all my user data will be preserved

Comment: @JakeGould I'm currently in the process of reinstalling a new macOS(after pressing Command+R), so I may not be able to perform that..

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Thank you so much!!!!!!!!! Problem solved after I reinstalled macOs!! And all my files are still there! What a relief!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope is not lost!

If you are able to boot from the [macOS recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) mode—via rebooting and holding down <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, you have two options:

1. **Repair Disk Permisions via Disk Utility**: This should be the quickest and easiest way to solve the issue. Simply launch “Disk Utility” then select the partition that has messed up permissions and hit “First Aid” from the menu options. Wait a bit and “Disk Utility” should be able to detect the messed up permissions and repair them.
2. **OS Reinstall**: This is a more radical—and time consuming—option, but it should work. The macOS installer will check the destination volume for an already existing OS—irregardless of permission state—and then be smart enough to reinstall on top of that setup without affecting the user files you need. That said—and to the best of my knowledge—**the reinstall of files is not what solves stuff like this**. Rather what happens when you upgrade or reinstall macOS is the process will run “First Aid” before doing anything else. *That* process will fix the permissions issue and then new OS files get installed.

So at the end of the day, running “First Aid” via “Disk Utility” will repair permissions in macOS. In Ubuntu? Unaware of an equivalent process, but if anyone out there knows of a way to reset Ubuntu permissions when they get messed up like this, please feel free to post an answer.